# morphia/mongo querying on a nested tree structure

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I have a Java/mongo object Node that can contain another Node, etc. 
So my structure in mongo is:

like Document->Node->Node->...

A Node has a name attribute, and I want to find all Documents that have a node (including any nested Nodes) that contains a certain name.

I was using dot notation to do something like:

```
query.field("document.node.name").equal(name)
```

but that only works if the parent node has a matching name.. what I need is some kind of wildcard to search for any name (document.node.node....name etc) that is in a Node object.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

There is no wildcard search in MongoDB.

You'd need to store the `Node`s somehow flattened to perform that query. You could for example store the hierarchy (the parent chain) in each `Node` so that you could recreate the hierarchy with your client application code.

The most commonly used structures are very well documented [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/).